# How to backup all db by pg_dump in batch file - postgres

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I try to backup all DB from postgres, but i dont know how to do that in the loop.
pg_dumpall isnt good idea for me, couse i got over 1k DB and it will be grown.

```
@echo off

set BASELOG=LOG
set BACKUPDIR=C:/postgres/backups/
set BACKUPDIR2=C:\postgres\backups
set PGHOST=localhost
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGBIN="C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/"
set FILELOG=log.txt

set BACKUPDIRDATE="%BACKUPDIR%%date%/"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
 set dow=%%i
 set month=%%j
 set day=%%k
 set year=%%l
)
if not exist %BACKUPDIRDATE% mkdir %BACKUPDIRDATE%

(
echo Backup start %date%  %time%
%PGBIN%pg_dump -w -i -h %PGHOST% -U %PGUSER% -F c -b -v -f     "%BACKUPDIRDATE%%LOG%.compressed" %BASELOG%
echo End of backup %BASELOG%

FORFILES /p %BACKUPDIR2% /s /D -7 /C "cmd /c rd /S /Q @path"
echo Files are deleted
 )>> %BACKUPDIRDATE%%FILELOG% 2>&1
```

Can someone explain me how to get list of all DB and then loop them?

I tried %PGBIN%psql /list but this doesnt work

Comment: Its not the exact answer but it may be useful for you  http://serverfault.com/a/59847

Comment: # get list of databases in system , exclude the tempate dbs
DBS=$($PSQL -l -t | egrep -v 'template[01]' | awk '{print $1}')
Doesnt work in windows batch

Comment: make a txt with the databases list and add a for IN (dblist.txt) using the -d parameter

Comment: @FrankNStein coudl you post example of that? i know there shoudl be some loop with that (or not?), but i dont know how to handle that

Comment: @Pan-Pieczar I out my suggestion on answer, the comments is too short

Answer (score 2):

Please, re-check the scrip, i do it on the fly. I don't remember what is the -w on pg_dump.
In this way you will obtain a file for each db. 
And as a suggestion, use \ instead / when speak about folder paths on Windows
Excuse my english.

```
@echo off

set BASELOG=LOG
set BACKUPDIR=C:/postgres/backups/
set BACKUPDIR2=C:\postgres\backups
set PGHOST=localhost
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGBIN="C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/"
set FILELOG=log.txt

set BACKUPDIRDATE="%BACKUPDIR%%date%/"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
 set dow=%%i
 set month=%%j
 set day=%%k
 set year=%%l
)
if not exist %BACKUPDIRDATE% mkdir %BACKUPDIRDATE%

(

if exist dbs.lst del dbs.lst
psql -h %PGHOST% -p 5432 -U %PGUSER% -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;" -o "dbs.lst"

for /f %%a IN (dbs.lst) DO (

    echo Backup start %date%  %time%
    %PGBIN%pg_dump -w -i -h %PGHOST% -U %PGUSER% -F c -b -v -f "%BACKUPDIRDATE%-%%a.compressed" %%a
    echo End of backup %BASELOG%

)

FORFILES /p %BACKUPDIR2% /s /D -7 /C "cmd /c rd /S /Q @path"
echo Files are deleted
 )>> %BACKUPDIRDATE%%FILELOG% 2>&1
```